# Why are NPN and PNP transistors connected to the gate of NMOSFET in this circuit?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I am trying to make a simple BMS by referring to [the circuit on this site.](https://oshwlab.com/mopac1851/Arduino_Balance_Charger-e669293c629b40e0b2dd404c5dc6a1d4)

[image]

I want to know why the digital outputs of the Arduino are not directly connected to the gate of the MOSFET, but are connected through an NPN transistor and a PNP transistor and why the B3 11V1 battery connected to the PNP transistor's emitter.

Comment: Think of them as level translators.

Comment: FYI, this is a terrible BMS. Huge idle current, ridiculously oversized transistors, and, who knows what the MCU is doing, I'm sure there's bugs on that side too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are level translators.  The MCU looks to be a 5V device.  The designer is wanting to drive the gate of the FET with 11V.  So the transistors are controlling the 11V with a 5V signal.